# Hosting Silverlight app with Forms Authentication on IIS 7

Tags: silverlight, iis-7, forms-authentication

Is it possible to get Silverlight ASP.NET Forms authentication working on IIS?

I followed sample http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2008/05/03/accessing-the-asp-net-authentication-profile-and-role-service-in-silverlight.aspx and it works on ASP.NET Development Server but when hosting on IIS I get Error: "You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.".

Any success out there?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you get rid of this "**"You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers".**" error. You need to enable Anonymous authentication on your deployed application. That's it.
But Enabling forms authentication along with anonymous authentication is what I am looking for. Point is that I need to get users download my .xap which requires anonymous authentication but once .xap is downloaded in user's silverlight player, it wants to use forms authentication for log in. Multiple authentication at once doesn't seem to work for me. If you know anything in this regard, let me know please.

Comment: Hi singlepoint, have you solved your anonymous and forms authentication issue? I'm facing with the same problem.

Comment: It's great that you've helped with solving the error message issue. But then you raise a further question about multiple authentication types in a different scenario. You should really ask this as a separate question because a) it makes your answer clearer and b) you're more likely to get an answer to your question.